# Checking individual operation content by API level APIM policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy

In my RESTFUL API,
there are two operations:

/getuser/{userid} --- Get method to get the user details
/users  -- Post method to create a new user.

Now, I want to add a API level policy to check the content when the method is POST.

What could be the easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

this is possible in Azure (APIM), you can add policies at the API level to define behaviors that affect all operations within that API. If you want to apply a policy specifically for the POST method in your scenario, you can use a conditional statement in your policies to check the HTTP method and then apply the desired logic.

let me show you how to add an API level policy to check the content only when the method is POST

```html
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Method.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))">
            <!-- Your content checking logic here -->
            <validate-content />
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```